# Hiding Achievement Banners Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

On Android, is it possible to hide achievement banners? We'd like to override the banner they use with our own. After some research I don't believe you can but I would like confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can override the `setViewForPopups (View gamesContentView)` method so that you can use your custom view?

Reference: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#setViewForPopups(android.view.View)